# Finding unique elements when using include?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am trying to create the game mastermind. The setter code array is a dummy array of colors that will change randomly each game. Player guess is also dummy elements to portray what I am trying to achieve. My first iteration goes through setter_code and checks whether player_guess has the same color in the same position. My second iterator goes through player guess and checks whether setter_code includes that color anywhere in the array. However, my problem is that as you can see - when there are 2 duplicate colors in the setter code, but only one in the guess the iterator will output that there are 2 reds in the setter code as it will find the one red both times it iterates through the guess array. I changed the iterator to include .uniq but then realised that if the setter_code did include 2 of the same color and the player guess had 2 of the same color it would then actually need to output that there were 2 matches. Is there a way for me to (like I have done with the ? and ! in the first iteration) remove the red that it matches first so that the second red would not see it?

```
setter_code = ["blue", "red", "blue", "orange"]
player_guess = ["red", "orange", "red", "yellow"]
result = []

setter_code.each_with_index do |color, i|
      if color == player_guess[i]
          result << "O"
          setter_code[i] = "?"
          player_guess[i] = "!"
      end
    end

    player_guess.each do |user_color|
      if setter_code.include? user_color
        result << "o"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `count` function like:
`setter_code.count{ |x| x == user_color } == 1`

Answer (score 0):

"My second iterator goes through player guess and checks whether setter_code includes that color anywhere in the array"

With arrays you can avoid loops to check for their differences

```
 missed= setter_code - player_guess
 guessed = setter_code & player_guess
```